# Highcharts: Area clickable

Tags: highcharts

I have an area Highchart chart.
Added a click event to the chart, like this:

```
plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    cursor: 'Pointer',
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    events: {
                        click: function(event) {
                          alert("hi there");
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
```

It works fine. The problem is that you can only click very near to a line, but not on the area below the line, it is not clickable.

Is there a setting that I overlooked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you can do exactly what you want out of the box. The chosen answer was only looking at events for the PlotOptions object; you need to look at events for the Chart object.

Documentation and example at:
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-events--click

When you click on the background, it fires the event.

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                alert ('x: '+ event.xAxis[0].value +', y: '+
                      event.yAxis[0].value);
            }
        }        
    },
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use this [`trackByArea: true`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.trackByArea) area function in [`plotOptions`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions)

> **trackByArea:** Boolean
>
> Since 1.1.6 Whether the whole area or just the
>   line should respond to mouseover tooltips and other mouse or touch
>   events. Defaults to false.

Combine this with the [`click event`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.events.click)

> **click:** Function
>
> Fires when the series is clicked. The this keyword
>   refers to the series object itself. One parameter, event, is passed to
>   the function. This contains common event information based on jQuery
>   or MooTools depending on which library is used as the base for
>   Highcharts. Additionally, event.point holds a pointer to the nearest
>   point on the graph.

ex:

```
plotOptions: { area: { **trackByArea: true**, marker: { enabled: false },..
```

Comment: Hi your answer was useful to me ,  but it works only when on series is visible, does something else needs to be done in order to be able to click any of the  visible series ?

Comment: I agree that this answer should be the accepted one. It is more specific to the question asked than the one that is accepted.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-area-events--click), the `click` event only covers clicking on the series itself, so it will not register click events for clicking beneath the line.

To do what you want, you may need to handle things on your own by using the [`mouseOver` event](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-area-events--mouseOver). Unforutnately, this event fires when the mouse hovers over the graph, which would mean you'd need to figure out where the mouse is on the graph and so forth.

Alternatively, you could modify the highcharts source code to suit your needs, or extend it, but in any case, I do not believe that this can be done easily.

Comment: See my newly posted answer below; this event has been supported in Highcharts since 1.2.0 (2010-02-23).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the click chart event when clicking on the plot background, like so:

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert ('x: '+ event.xAxis[0].value +', y: '+
                          event.yAxis[0].value);
                }
            }        
        },
        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});​
```

Here's the link to the documentation:

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-events--click

Hope that helps.

Comment: When you do a click, how can you show in the alert the datapoint value that was clicked?